# PowerPoint 2010 Developer Tab - “Code” Group Disabled

Tags: microsoft-powerpoint, macros, vba, microsoft-powerpoint-2010

The "Code" group on my Developer tab in PowerPoint 2010 is entirely disabled. For clarity, the "Visual Basic", "Macros", and "Macro Security" buttons are greyed/grayed out. I am also unable to open VB Editor via Alt+F11. Note that these options (including VB Editor) are available in Excel and Outlook of the same install.

I have reinstalled Office 2010, ensuring that Shared Tools are selected, with no success. I have searched through the registry for any obvious keys that might be responsible for this and found nothing. I have also searched for quite a while on other sites and came up with no answers.

Can you help? Is there a policy or registry key that might be disabling these functions?

Comment: Check the trust center - `file - options - trust center - trust center settings - disable all macros with notification` and it will notify you to enable macros on projects where you want them.

Comment: Unfortunately, that isn't the problem. That setting is already set to that effect. Visual Basic itself is completely inaccessible in the program.

Comment: Have you tried setting it to 'enabled', maybe the prompt isn't displaying. Does this happen on all presentations or only certain ones?

Comment: It's not about enabling macros - the entire VB feature set is absent in PowerPoint. So no presentations can be edited from a coding perspective.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Found the, er, problem. It was a policy setting under 
`HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Policies\Microsoft\Office\14.0\powerpoint`

Comment: Did you add something to the registry there?

Comment: @Sagar I wish I'd put more details in that answer, as 8 years later (+2 days), I don't remember what I did. I also have a different machine now, and so I can't even check. It may have been related to the VBAWarnings key, but I can't be sure. I may have also resolved it using Group Policy Editor.